# Removing elements in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code where I compare two arrays for similar values, then remove the similar values from one of the arrays. Is there a better way of writing this piece of code?

```
UpdateAddedTasksAfterDelete() {
    var tasksToRemove = [];
    var updatedTasks = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.deletedTasks.length; i++) {
        if (this.addedTasks.indexOf(this.deletedTasks[i]) > -1) { tasksToRemove.push(this.deletedTasks[i]); }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.addedTasks.length; i++) {
        if (this.addedTasks.indexOf(tasksToRemove[i]) == -1) { updatedTasks.push(this.addedTasks[i]); }
    }

    this.addedTasks = updatedTasks;
}
```

Comment: Your code is broken - and very convoluted. In your 2nd loop, `i` goes from zero to `addedTasks.length`, but it's used to access elements in a different array, which likely has a different length. Point is, you end up with nonsensical results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to what your goal is here, but here are a few options, depending on which outcome you are hoping for...

If your goal is to **take two arrays, combine them, and discard any duplicate values**, using a Set will automatically discard the values that appear more than once for you.

Simply use:

```
var mySet = new Set(array1)
array2.forEach((item)=>{mySet.add(item)});
```

Then convert the set back to an array if you need it specifically in array form, using the spread operator:

```
var finalArray = [...mySet]
```

'finalArray' will now hold each unique value from the combination of your two original arrays.

If your goal is to **compare two arrays, removing values from the first array that are present in the second**, use filter:

```
var finalArray = array1.filter((item)=>{return !array2.includes(item)})
```

'finalArray' will now hold all values of array1 that do not also exist in array2.

Comment: Thank you, I should have been more specific in what I was looking for. Filter does the trick.

Comment: You can shorten it a bit to `.filter(item => !array2.includes(item))`